# What is the name of the movie from the 80's about scientists that build a machine that helps people share their experiences?

Tags: movie, communication, story-identification

My boyfriend remembers parts of this movie, but not any actors or the name. He said that there is a machine that they put on their heads and it takes their experiences and gives them to another person. At one point, a woman was hooked up and she has a heartattack. The scientists disconnect her from the other person and they watch what she sees as she dies. If they hadn't removed the other person, they would have died as well. This machine is supposed to help people experience things that they can't normally experience, like a person with no legs experiencing skydiving, with no danger.

Comment: probable duplicate of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/94540/movie-identification-people-record-their-experiences-on-reel-to-reel (which is newer but has the most complete accepted answer)

Answer (score 25):

It was [*Brainstorm*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0085271/).

It was Natalie Wood's last movie and directed by Douglas Trumbull.  He was hoping to use it to launch his new 70mm film format.

They had a recorder that connected with a headband and stored data from experiences on some kind of tape.  In one incident, a man puts it on while having sex with a woman and someone else takes the tape of that experience and edits it so it plays back only the orgasm and makes a loop of it.  They find him the next morning in convulsions from having gone though it so much that he couldn't disengage and turn it off.

One character has a heart attack and realizes they are dying, so they put the recorder on.  The rest of the movie is about someone else who is intent on playing that tape back to see what the experience of death was like and if that revealed anything about the afterlife.

Comment: Very good movie. I watched it just recently and it was better than I had recalled.

Comment: I remeber the bit where one guy puts himself into a loop of non stop shagging and gets fitter as a result!

Answer (score 3):

Dreamscape?

http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0087175/

Answer (score 2):

Could it be [Strange Days](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strange_Days_%28film%29)? It's not from the 80s but it does sound similar.

Comment: Sounded like this one to me, too, until I read the answer on Brainstorm.

Answer (score 0):

There was an episode on "new" Outer Limits that can be of particular interest to you.

Episode 02x05, "[Mind over Matter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mind_Over_Matter_%28The_Outer_Limits%29)":

> Dr. Sam Stein develops a machine that allows a person to connect themselves directly to the brain of another and experience their thoughts and feelings. Intended for use with coma patients, he suddenly gets the chance to use it with a colleague who is comatose after an accident.